# Save API response to the browser?

Tags: api, cookies, local-storage, session-storage

I am fetching some date from an API and need to have access to this same data on another page, but don't want to request the same data again from the server.

I am trying to  find a more efficient and quicker way to access the data at the second request.

Should I save the first request response saved in the browser, session storage, local storage or cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not cookie!

Saving data in LocalStorage or IndexedDB is how it's usually done.

Basically you need to read about Service Workers, those are used for caching and many other things as well, but most tutorials start with caching - exactly what you need.

I would recommend to start here: [Google Progressive Web Apps Training](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa)